# Can the motherboard of a inkjet printer be reprogrammed to do something else?

Tags: reverse-engineering

Is there any way to use the motherboard of an inkjet printer (like how you would use an Arduino), to build a CNC plotter?

Comment: It is likely having some proprietary ASIC(s) as controller. Highly unlikely you can figure these out.

Comment: It's certainly possible to hack your own firmware, after all the manufacturer did it. As the comments say though, you will have a hard time figuring some things out, like a circuit diagram to know what pin functions need to be for the various chips. It would be much easier to scavenge the parts you want and hook them to an Arduino stepper driver shield. You can even remove the motherboard completely and just use the printer shell/mechanisms with a new board.

Comment: @RonBeyer the manufacturer has one or two advantages, like the schematic and datasheets for everything on the board. That makes life a bit easier, even if the OP has the same skills as teh manufacturer...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Which is why I pointed out that the OP would have a "hard time figuring some things out, like a circuit diagram"...

Comment: @BrianDrummond so true....been searching for hours for datasheets or even a schematic and can't find any. Still searching tho... really hope I find something

Comment: Re your edit: it's still a fairly bad question for this site. Yes it can, but not practical or easy. You would have to start from scratch and only really if you had insider knowledge of the parts. Best you can hope for is to reuse the motors and rails.

Comment: I am not sure about printers, but for other consumer appliances (like TVs) I have found that you can get a technical manual aimed at repairmen.  Some of them actually have some fairly detailed information in them.  Sometimes this even includes a lot of the schematics and parts list.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of the interwebs, anything that is hackable and half useful has already been done and published. In this instance it seems there was not much interest in your printer, so consider it in the ‘too hard basket’. That’s not to say it can’t be done.